# Pyspark - filter to select max value

Tags: pyspark, filter

I have a date column with column type "string". It has multiple dates and several rows of data for each date.

I'd like to filter the data to select the most recent (max) date however, when I run it, the code runs but ends up populating an empty table.

Currently I am typing in my desired date manually because I am under the impression that no form of max function will work since the column is of string type.

```
This is the code I am using

extract = raw_table.drop_duplicates() \
          .filter(raw.as_of_date == '2022-11-25')
```

and what I desire to do is make this automated. Something on the lines of

```
.filter(raw.as_of_date == max(as_of_date)
```

Please advise on how to convert column type from string to date, how to code to select max date and why my hardcoding results in an empty table

Comment: you can first calculate the `max` in a new column and then use that column as the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to calculate the max of the date in a column and then use that column for filtering as spark does not allow aggregations in filters.

you might need something like the following

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd

raw_table.drop_duplicates(). \
    withColumn('max_date', func.max('as_of_date').over(wd.partitionBy())). \
    filter(func.col('as_of_date') == func.col('max_date')). \
    drop('max_date')
```